# Vuex: Can't tell why my getter is not sorting properly

Tags: vue.js, vuex

**store.js**

```
getComments(state) {
   let allComments = state.allComments;

    allComments = allComments.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.stamped > b.stamped;
    });
    
     return allComments;
}
```

`allComments` is  an array of objects that  are comments and `stamped` is a timestamp field on them.

They are being returned as follows:  `[{stamped:  1595893492}, {stamped:1595893432}, {stamped: 1595893496}]`.
It's not even in increase  or decreasing order...the lowest (oldest) is the 2nd  value returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems...

1. You are mutating state in your getter
2. Your comparison function is returning a boolean but it should return an integer

You can solve both of these using the following

```js
getComments: state => [...state.allComments].sort((a, b) => a.stamped - b.stamped)
```

The spread-operator creates a shallow copy of your `allComments` state property so you're no longer mutating it with `sort`.

See [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) for an understanding of comparators and the value they should return.

Comment: thank  you.  Question about how I'm mutating state in the getter. I'm  setting `let allComments = state.allComments;` but  `state.allComments`  never gets changed.

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort()` changes the array in-place. `state.allComments` would be getting changed but you probably don't see it due to your broken comparator